Typescript infer generics with callback argument
I'm having a hard time inferring TypeScript generic arguments in a function. The idea is that I just specify one generic argument T and the generic U is inferred from a callback, like so:
async function get<T, U>(url: string, transform: (arg: T) => U) {
  // this is externally created
  const storage: Record<string, [string, U]> = {}

  // check if it's in cache
  const cached = storage[url]
  // fetch and check if modified
  const res = await fetch(url, { headers: {
    ...(cached && { 'If-Modified-Since': cached[0] }),
  } })
  // if not, return cached
  if (res.status === 304)
    return cached[1]
  // else transform it with callback
  const data = transform((await res.json()) as T)
  // then store transformed into cache
  storage[url] = [res.headers.get('last-modified')!, data]
  // and return transformed data
  return data
}

The function fetches a resource over the network, which comes in raw form, and I'm storing last modified time. So when asked, I query the server, and if it responds with 304 Not Modified then I reuse storage cached value (transformed). If it has been modified, then it should transform the raw data using the transform argument and then save that value into cache, finally returning it.
Thing is, I'd like to specify only one generic argument and infer the second one from the transform function, like so:
// type should be: number
const sample = await get<number>('sample', res => res + 1)

// type should be: string
const other = await get<{ hello: string }>('other', res => res.hello)

Currently, I'm having an error, saying that get needs two generic arguments instead of just one.
So, how can I get TypeScript to infer the U generic argument having transform function as reference?
I already tried with a set of infer and other stuff, with no luck. Also, if I set U = any then the type inference breaks, setting the return value as any regardless of transform function.

This isn't possible in TS. See the linked q/a for more information and for workarounds. The usual approach is currying as shown in this playground link.
